# Checked dynamically binding dropdown checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dropdown checkbox with data binded dynamically.I pass value through cookie then the value equal to the dropdown checkbox it checked.For example

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //binding dropdown checkbox code, after that
    var cookievalue = getCookie("Cookieval");
    if (cookievalue != null) {
        $(window).bind("load", function() {
            $("input[id='dropdownchecklistid'][value='" + cookievalue + "']").prop("checked", true);
        });
    }
});
```

But it doesn't work first time loading the page

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle so I can see this happening there? I'm pretty sure the error is related to .prop().  I need to see the html also.

Comment: also why do you have ([value='" + cookievalue + "']") what is that there for? I think you can just remove that.

Comment: It's working when I reload it.May be because of cache.

Comment: Based on the cookie value checkbox in the dropdown checked.Binding data in the dropdown is dynamically created.

Comment: also why are you binding to load on window? document ready does same thing? I am working on JSFiddle right now to help you, give me 5 minutes.

Comment: take a look at this, I got it to checkbox right away first time. (https://jsfiddle.net/x11joex11/qxoh2tfL/).  You don't need the window.bind("load"), document.ready() does it for you when the dom is ready.  I didn't have your cookie function so I just put "1" to simulate getting a value, change it to null to see it change.

Comment: First the page is load it doesn't affect.when I refresh the page it's work

Comment: I think it has to do with the bind("load") you have, did you look at my jsfiddle? The other issue if its still happening might be in your getCookie() function can you list that for me too if its still happening?

Comment: I need to check the checkbox with the value equal to cookie.I get cookie value.I think the problem occurred due to dynamically bind the dropdown checkbox list.